# Install my .app release file on iOS device file via terminal from Mac

Tags: ios, terminal, usb, file-transfer

I've seen a number of similar questions asked, but I'm still not sure they answer my own question. I also read [this](https://docs.monaca.io/en/products_guide/monaca_ide/deploy/non_market_deploy/).

My specific requirements (or lack thereof) are:

- I don't want my app to appear on the app store
- I just want to install it manually on a number of iOS devices.
- I don't mind using the terminal or a third party app.
- I don't mind if the user has to manually select "trust this developer/app" from within the iOS device before being able to run the app.

I'm a little confused because what I've read says that I need a developer account, or Enterprise account, to install.

But how is this so? XCode, for example, installs the build perfectly, and I don't have a developer account. Is there not an XCode terminal comman I can execute to simply install the `.app` file on the device?

Or would this require jail-breaking? If so, how come? XCode does it just fine...

I understand Apple would probably want to restrict this behaviour due to security, but I wanted to ask. Perhaps the only way really is an Apple developer/Enterprise account.

---

Possible solutions could be:

- [Fruitstrap](https://github.com/phildrip/fruitstrap) => "Install and debug iPhone apps without using Xcode. Designed to work on unjailbroken devices."
- [Sideloading](http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/12/howto-sideload-apps-iphone-ipad-xcode/) => But I think this requires revealing your code.

Comment: Sideloading looks like a sketchy business with the Ad-Hod profiles (which kinda breaks the Apple rules about using these) and I would definitely not use it.

Comment: Tho you are not exposing the code to them, it just looks like you are adding some kind of ad-hoc profile of theirs to sign your app with it. They wont get access to your code with this, but still I would not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** for the purpose of building the app on the device as a debug build straight from XCode, you don't need a payed Developer account, you just need to register as a Apple Developer & login to XCode with that account and you should be to build debug builds on your device.

You have a few alternatives here:

1/ export the `.ipa` file after you build a release version of your app in XCode and distribute it to the devices, you want to install it on. You will however need to sign your app with your certificate of iOS developer. More about it here:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?34616,HowTo%3A+Create+an+.ipa+file+from+XCode

2/ Basically the same thing as above, but you can use some 3rd party service for build distribution (which is easier than distributing `.ipa` files around. Something like [Crashlytics Beta](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html) or something. Even [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) would work, tho I am not sure if app in store is not required.

Either way, you will have to deal with code signing and need to have a Apple Developer account, unless you distribute it via building it straight to the phone as a debug build.

Comment: Thanks. I could meet up with the client and install directly on the devices. It's an ongoing thing, so I'm not fussed about smooth deployment as yet. Can iron this out as time goes on. This would probably be the easiest, except having to have a meeting with all the iPads at once !

If I will need a developer account to do either of your alternatives, then I may as well just distribute it on the App Store. That wouldn't be a problem. I can add on my developer fee as part of the license fee !

Comment: PS I'm flying with Kiwi in a few months :-D

Comment: No problem. The general rule of thumb is - if you want to install your app without having the phones connected, you will have to have an paid Developer Account to distribute `.ipa` files (either by sending them or by Beta/TF service). Otherwise, you can build it from XCode with the target phone connected as debug version, but it cannot be distributed.
For both of these things above, you will need an Apple Developer account, unpaid for the debug or paid for `.ipa` distribution.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear that. If you have any issues with your booking, you can contact me :D

Comment: Thank you. And it's all much clearer now, thank you for your help. Just one more question... can I not install a "release" version from XCode via USB if I don't have a paid account?